# Spring beans unresolved in IntelliJ

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea

I started a project with IntelliJ that worked well but did something that broke it. Here is my *applicationContext.xml* file.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean class="foo.Bar" />
</beans>
```

When inspecting the file I get the error

> Cannot resolve bean 'foo.Bar'

The same thing happens for all classes I try to put in my spring configuration file. Any clue about that ?

Here are the screenshots :

spring file error : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwhIWYS5TjDRaWxjUzhBbDVnNk0/view?usp=sharing

spring facet : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwhIWYS5TjDRb1RHbGlCOW9xeTg/view?usp=sharing

I use Maven to import jars and the classes exist in my classpath.
But the code assist doesn't give me any tip when I edit the bean class property.

Comment: is foo.Bar class in classpath and the class public?

Comment: Change  'foo.Bar' to  'fooBar'

Comment: See my screenshots for more info

Answer (score 1):

Without a screenshot of IntelliJ its hard to find out, but here is my shortlist:

1) did you configure the IntelliJ Spring facet to include your xml file? To check that, hit F4 while selecting the root of the project tree and see the Facet configuration for Spring. There your xml file must be listed.

2) you really have package "foo" with the Class "Bar.java" under your "sources" folder in IDEA ?

Comment: 1) yes 2) no ! ;) See my screenshots.

Comment: this is a complete different picture because in your screenshots its not foo.bar which is the issue but spring classes itself. The classpath didnt reflect the maven spring dependencies somehow.

Comment: In fact whatever class (for example a custom foo.Bar class that exist in src/main/java) I put in the Spring config file, the result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Without full log-trace, I can only make assumption on why this is happening

1. Did not include required dependencies (JARs)
2. You have not created foo.Bar class in your classpath

Comment: I suppose the second option is the good one but only the spring file can't find the classes, I've no problem within my code.